# Заполнить поле значением из другого поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица members, в ней есть поля username и email. Нужно заполнить поле username емеилами, в случае если оно пустое

Comment: открываете любую книгу по mysql, ищите описание инструкций `update` и условий `where`

Comment: и про конструкцию `IS NULL`

Comment: а где здесь написано что там обязательно NULL ?

Comment: @JonnyManowar ну дак и напишите вопрос тогда корректно, а не как попало. Тут гадать что ли люди должны, что у вас под Пустым понимается.

Comment: значит что пустая строка, зачем придумывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update members set username = email where username = ''`

Comment: Разве с `NULL` можно сравнивать?)

Comment: @SanekZhitnik сравнить то можно, но результат будет не тот.

Comment: В вопросе не сказано, что пустое поле содержит именно null.

Comment: **To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators** .... **You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as = ... to test for NULL** [мануал](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: @NikolayTorgov в вопросе то и не сказано. но вы сами сраниваете меинно с null, и делаете это неправильно.

Comment: Справедливо, что-ж